# Setting up the path of Jdk

Tags: path

One of my tutor has told me to set the path of jdk in system variables as variable name = Java_path
Variable value = C:/Program Files/jdk 1.8 and he also told me to add this link into
Variable name = path
Variable value = some other paths;C:/Program Files/jdk 1.8/bin;

My doubt is can we enter the variable value of path as = some other paths;Java_path/bin; or is it entered in other format? Please help me get out of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to do this is to declare a JAVA_HOME system variable which points to root folder of the JDK installation (e.g `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212`).

Then you can add this to your path system variable. In the path system variable you would add this - `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`

Where `%JAVA_HOME%` points to the root of the JDK installation and the bin folder contains all the executable binaries. Notice that you have to use `%JAVA_HOME%` and not just `JAVA_HOME`

Usually the `\bin` directory is added to the path as it contains all the executable binaries.

You can directly add `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_212\bin` to your path. That will also work perfectly fine.