# Flutter application build fails, throws "Failed to install sdk components"

Tags: android, windows, flutter, sdk

When I run flutter application on my android physical device I get this.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Failed to install the following SDK components:
      build-tools;30.0.3 Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3
  Install the missing components using the SDK manager in Android Studio.
```

I have already tried accepting licenses using "flutter --android-licenses" as mentioned in some other solutions.

I have tried uninstalling everything and reinstalling android studio and flutter. Feels like I am missing something.

Comment: try to create a emulator device, hope it will navigate you

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I have a emulator setup already. I tried running it on a emulator. gives me the same exception

Comment: can you include `flutter doctor -v` and can you check the sdk tools section

Comment: adding jdk to my system variable fixed it for me. I uninstall and reinstalled android studio. i followed this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57106647/setting-up-the-path-of-jdk#:~:text=The%20usual%20way%20to%20do,8.0_212%20).&text=Usually%20the%20%5Cbin%20directory%20is,Program%20Files%5CJava%5Cjdk1.

Comment: you can close the question as duplicate on that case